# Can I prevent cells being dirtied when a Workbook opens [Mac]?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have a UDF that I'm using throughout a Workbook, when I save and reopen the Workbook and then try to recalculate a single cell, Excel will update that cell but it will also recalculate every other cell containing that formula in the Workbook.

Here's a simple formula that demonstrates this issue:

```
Public Function MyFormula(a As Integer, b As Integer) As Integer

    Debug.Print "calculating: " & Application.Caller.Address

    MyFormula = a * b    

End Function
```

I would expect that after recalculating a single cell to see a single log statement, but I'm actually seeing 4 (I have 4 cells with this UDF in the Workbook).

I'm guessing that when I save & reopen the Workbook, Excel is marking the cells as "Dirty" and in need of recalculation, but that doesn't make sense. According to the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/excel-recalculation#dependence-dirty-cells-and-recalculated-cells) dirty cells are defined as those who's dependancies have changed:

> When new data or new formulas are entered, Excel marks all the cells  that depend on that new data as needing recalculation. Cells that are marked in this way are known as dirty.

My UDF isn't volatile and I haven't altered any dependancies, so why is Excel recalculating the all cells and how can I stop it from doing so?

(By the way, I'm aware that Manual calculation mode exists. I'd like to be able to use Automatic mode and allow automatic cell updates, but just only when dependancies have changed)

I've since found that this issue is only present on Excel for Mac (tested on the 2016 version).

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem in Excel 2013. The only time when the UDF logs multiple entries is when there are some changes made to VBA code. Can you give exact steps to reproduce?

Comment: Create a new workbook. Enter multiple formulas into different cells. Save the workbook. Close and reopen Excel. Double-click on a cell with a formula and press Enter to recalculate. Excel will then recalculate all cells.

Comment: Definitely no repro in 2013: new workbook, pasted the code in new module, entered 10 random cells with this UDF, saved, closed, reopened. After editing and confirming one of the cells the only output was `calculating: $C$3`.

Comment: @BrakNicku that's strange. Thanks for trying to reproduce though. Perhaps it's because I'm using a 2016 version of Excel for Mac

Comment: After testing on Windows Excel 2016 I can confirm that I'm unable to reproduce the issue and Excel recalculates only the cells requested. It seems that this is purely a Mac issue, I'll update the original question to reflect this.

Comment: If it is some version specific defect then there are only 2 ways left - wait for the fix or try to implement some workaround. There is not enough data in the question to suggest one, I can only guess it is all about avoiding some time consuming calculations, so maybe some global variable flag can be of help.